# Corrupted mariadb database. Unable to mysql_upgrade, mysqlcheck or mysqldump

Tags: mysql, mariadb

This morning my mariadb database wouldn't start.

It seems I have some corrupted InnoDB tables and it will only start with `innodb_force_recovery` set (value `1` gets it to start).

I have tried `mysql_upgrade --force` but as soon as this gets to the corrupted table, it fails with error `2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when executing 'REPAIR NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG VIEW ... '`

Using `mysqlcheck`, again it gets as far as the corrupted table and then fails with `2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when executing 'CHECK TABLE ... '` and the all subsequent checks fail with `2002: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (111) when executing 'CHECK TABLE ... '`

Very similar when trying to use mysqldump. I have followed the suggestions [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97846/mysqldump-error-2013) with `mysqldump mydatabase --skip-lock-tables --hex-blob --skip-extended-insert > /root/db_backup/mydatabase.sql` but again, as soon as it hits the first corrupt table I get `mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'show create table "my_table"': Lost connection to MySQL server during query (2013)`

I have tried increasing the `innodb_force_recovery` value up to 6 but to no avail.

I have also added the following to my.cnf

```
net_read_timeout=7200 
net_write_timeout=7200
max_allowed_packet=1024M
```

It is mariadb 10.2.28 running on Centos 7

Answer (score 0):

We had this happen to a couple of our servers the last couple of days. We had some luck with rolling back to a previous version of mariadb but you may have to export the dbs, drop and re-import the dbs. We have a couple of different server providers and it happened with both. The one provider told us about certain version having the problem.

And it goes without saying make sure you have backups before doing anything that would lose data.

These are the versions our server host gave us that may cause these problems:
10.1.42
10.2.28
10.3.19
10.4.9